# PHP preg match with line ends in Linux and Windows

Tags: php

This code works on Linux but fails to match on Windows:

```
if ( preg_match ( "~<meta name='date' content='(.*)'>\n<meta name='time' content='(.*)'>\n<meta name='venue' content='(.*)'>\n~", file_get_contents($filename), $matches) ) 
...
```

I guess the line end coding is wrong. How should I modifiy the pattern to be 
end-coding independent?

Comment: xml/html + regex = [BAD](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068). Use DOM instead. it'll also free you from worrying about linebreak characters.

Comment: Thanks, but DOM cannot give precisely same match behaviour and I cannot afford change. If 100% back-compatibility were not required, yes I would use DOM.

Comment: `//meta[@name='time']` isn't accurate enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows line endings are:

```
   "\r\n"
```

**The simplest solution is:**

```
if (preg_match ("~<meta name='date' content='(.*)'>\n<meta name='time' content='(.*)'>\n<meta name='venue' content='(.*)'>\n~", file_get_contents($filename), $matches)
  ||
  preg_match("~<meta name='date' content='(.*)'>\r\n<meta name='time' content='(.*)'>\r\n<meta name='venue' content='(.*)'>\r\n~", file_get_contents($filename), $matches))
```

**The correct solution probably is:**

```
if (preg_match("~<meta name='date' content='(.*)'>[\r]?\n<meta name='time' content='(.*)'>[\r]?\n<meta name='venue' content='(.*)'>[\r]?\n~", file_get_contents($filename), $matches))
```

**That said,** you probably really should use another method for dealing with HTML & XML. There are parsers built specifically for that.

e.g. http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

On a side note, I haven't really tested either but iirc, they work. Regex is not something I use much.

EDIT:
Seems to work fine?

```
$file = "iorahgjajgasjgasjgasjgjaagaspokadsfgals<meta name='date'   content='(.*)'>\n<meta name='time' content='(.*)'>\n<meta name='venue' content='(.*)'>\niorahgjajgasjgasjgasjgjaagaspokadsfgals";

if (preg_match("~<meta name='date' content='(.*)'>\n<meta name='time' content='(.*)'>\n<meta name='venue' content='(.*)'>\n~", $file, $matches)
  || preg_match ("~<meta name='date' content='(.*)'>\r\n<meta name='time' content='(.*)'>\r\n<meta name='venue' content='(.*)'>\r\n~", file, $matches)) { 
  echo "Success";
}
else { 
  echo "Fail";
}

$file = "iorahgjajgasjgasjgasjgjaagaspokadsfgals<meta name='date' content='(.*)'>\r\n<meta name='time' content='(.*)'>\n<meta name='venue' content='(.*)'>\r\niorahgjajgasjgasjgasjgjaagaspokadsfgals";

if (preg_match ("~<meta name='date' content='(.*)'>[\r]?\n<meta name='time' content='(.*)'>[\r]?\n<meta name='venue' content='(.*)'>[\r]?\n~", $file, $matches)) {
  echo "Success";
}
else { 
  echo "Fail";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but both fail here. Is there some solution using multiline and ^$??

Comment: Are you sure? Can you show your file contents and what the place you are trying to match is?